# What is this circuit and what is used for?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have a question about this circuit. How is it used and what is it function. I can't find it anywhere in the literature.

[image]

Comment: Did you invent it then?

Comment: full wave rectifier with the diode reverse.

Comment: Where does the circuit come from?

Answer (score 3):

Positive period amplified (by 2 in this case), negative period without amplification, all transfered to negative. Vf of diode is neglected.

Blue is input and green the output.

[image]

Comment: How do you account for the fact that the power pins of the op-amp are unconnected?

Comment: Clearly, the schematic is missing the power rails for the sake of clarity and to avoid cluttering the diagram. Obviously no electronic design makes sense without voltage applied to it. I think Michal's response is totally valid in terms of the AC analysis. Being an AC circuit we should assume that a proper symmetric polarity is applied to it

Comment: Daniel, I tried to give you four upvotes, one for each previous comment.

Comment: Showing the power pins is vital to avoid ambiguity. Not showing them does not improve clarity but causes confusion. Given the nature of the question and the lack of response from the OP AND that there is no citation for the circuit, taking a stab in the dark about whether the power rails are connected or how they are connected is not, in my opinion, sufficient reason to justify making an answer.

Comment: In some cases, showing power is critical, especially if there is a question about whether the circuit under discussion is single sided, or if there may be input or output range issues.  None of that applies here, and the assumption of "properly powered" is fine, for both the answer and the originating question.